# get absolute url using in templatetag, name shows up but won't be directed to the link

Tags: python, django

I have this weird problem, I'm not sure where I did wrong. I created template tag, and inside there I have this code

```
<a href="{{ category.get_absolute_url }}">{{ c.name }}</a></li>
```

it shows all the names of category, but when I click them it won't be directed. I turned debug=true,but it doesn't give me errors. Here is the urls.py responsible for the above

```
url(r'^category/(?P<category_name_slug>[\w\-]+)/$', views.category, name='category'),
```

I'll post my views.py just in case

```
def category(request, category_name_slug):
    try:

                category = Category.objects.get(slug=category_name_slug)
                sort = request.GET["sort"].strip()
                sort_method = SortMethods[sort]
                page = request.GET["page"].strip()
    except KeyError:
                sort_method = SortMethods.score
                page = 1

    if sort_method == SortMethods.date:
                thread_list = Post.objects.filter(category=category).order_by("-pub_date")
    else:
                thread_list = Post.objects.filter(category=category)
                thread_list = sorted(thread_list, key=lambda x: x.get_score(), reverse=True)

    paginator = Paginator(thread_list, 30)

    try:
                posts = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
                posts = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
                posts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    context = {
                "posts": posts,
                "pages": paginator.page_range,
                "sort": sort_method.name,
                "categories":category,
              "cat_name_slug":category_name_slug,
        }
    return render(request, "main/index.html", context)
```

There must be something wrong with urls.py but what?

Edit 1:
Here is my models.py

```
class Category(models.Model): 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(Category, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __unicode__(self): 
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return '/%s/%s' % (self.id, self.slug)
```

the category page works like this:
http/~/category/nameofcategory

Comment: Could you add the code for the `Category` model where the `get_absolute_url` method is defined.

Comment: What URL does that href produce?

Comment: Why `category.get_absolute_url` and not `c.get_absolute_url` instead?

Comment: @crhodes I just added models.py

Comment: @JohnGordon it should produce category/slug/.... it works on the page if I just enter hardcode

Comment: @Pynchia thank you it works now, silly mistake ...thank you again

Answer (score 1):

it should've been {{ c.name }}
importance of naming!...should've named category not c...it just confused me more